# how can I make multiple ultrasonic sensors work at the same time using atmega32

Tags: c, sensors, avr

I am working on an auto-parking car robot and I am using 8 (hc-sr04) ultrasonic sensors (2 at each side) but the problem is that I am using atmega32 which has limited resources only 3 external interrupts and 3 timers (and even if using interrupts somehow works I might run into risk to have two interrupts triggered at the same time).

I am using this sensor : http://ram-e-shop.com/oscmax/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=907

I've tried using digital I/O pins with polling procedure but it didn't work.
here is the code for polling procedure:

```
unsigned int read_sonar(){
int dist_in_cm = 0;
init_sonar();                       // Setup pins and ports
trigger_sonar();                    // send a 10us high pulse


while(!(ECHO_PIN & (1<<ECHO_BIT))){   // while echo pin is still low
    USART_Message("echo pin low\r\n");
    trig_counter++;
     uint32_t max_response_time = SONAR_TIMEOUT;
    if (trig_counter > max_response_time){   // SONAR_TIMEOUT
        return TRIG_ERROR;
    }
}

TCNT1=0;                            // reset timer
TCCR1B |= (1<<CS10);              // start 16 bit timer with no prescaler
TIMSK |= (1<<TOIE1);             // enable overflow interrupt on timer1
overFlowCounter=0;                  // reset overflow counter
sei();                              // enable global interrupts

while((ECHO_PIN & (1<<ECHO_BIT))){    // while echo pin is still high
    USART_Message("echo pin high\r\n");
    if (((overFlowCounter*TIMER_MAX)+TCNT1) > SONAR_TIMEOUT){
        USART_Message("timeout");
        return ECHO_ERROR;          // No echo within sonar range

    }
};

TCCR1B = 0x00;                      // stop 16 bit timer with no prescaler
cli();                              // disable global interrupts
no_of_ticks = ((overFlowCounter*TIMER_MAX)+TCNT1);  // counter count

dist_in_cm = (no_of_ticks/(CONVERT_TO_CM*CYCLES_PER_US));   // distance in cm
return (dist_in_cm );}
```

This method doesn't work if I want to read all sensors at the same time, because it gets stuck in the loop for a while.

I also tried using freeRTOS to build a task that checks the state of pins like every 1msec but this won't be a time accurate.

any help?

Comment: It's difficult to help you since you don't mention much about your real-time requirements, but only mention that FreeRTOS is too inaccurate for your taste/needs. Please write some more about the requirements regarding timeliness.

Comment: Which kind of ultrasonic sensors do u use? How do you use them? Isn't the real question why polling didn't work?

Comment: Umm.. just how fast is your car parking itself?  You may be better keeping the auto-foot off the gas a bit..

Comment: @MemAllox I have just modified my question, sorry for not being clear at the first time.

Comment: @MortenJensen because I have to check the falling edge and the signal might goes to low after .5 msec, the periodic task which checks the state of the signal only works every 1msec, I can't make it work for less than 1 msec because this task checks the state of 8 sensors not just one so it needs the 1msec.

Comment: I you have 8 sensors, and the interface is just binary then, if all the sensors are connected to one port, you only need one read, and one compare against previous value, to detect any change on all 8 sensors.  You can do such an operation with a fast timer interrupt.  Any change at all, signal a semaphore.

Comment: If your controller is ARM-like, you can keep the previous value permanetly in the interrupt bank, in R8, say, and only copy changed values to some circular buffer before signaling the sema.

Comment: @MartinJames I also have to calculate for how long each pin has been high to be able to calculate the distance, does that mean besides the fast timer interrupt I have to use another 8 timers? because there is only three timers in atmega32

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that You use internal clock which is 8MHz I would try to handle this inside timer overflow interrupt and would use whole port to connect the sensors.

1. Use Timer in normal mode or [CTC](http://maxembedded.com/2011/07/avr-timers-ctc-mode/) mode (which I find quite intuitive) to ensure periodical interrupts. Set the appropriate period. Remember that the clock has pretty low frequency so don't exaggerate (I think that 0,25 ms will fit).
2. Connect the sensors to one port, e.g. PORTB. This is a nice situation because ATmega32 has 4 ports with pins numbered from 0-7 and you use 8 sensors so the register for the specific port can cover all of the pins and You can use one read to get states of all of the pins.
3. Implement the logic:

   ```
   volatile uint8_t sensors_states;
   volatile uint8_t read_flag = 0;

   ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
   {
       sensors_states = PORTB;
       read_flag = 1;
   }

   int main()
   {
       // Initialize peripherals ...

       // You must assume on your own how much time could the pin be held
       // in the same state. This is important because the number must not 
       // be bigger than max value for the type of the array
       uint8_t states_time[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
       uint8_t prev_sensors_states = PORTB;
       while(1)
       {
           // Wait until the flag will be set in the ISR
           if(read_flag)
           {
               for(uint8_t i = 0, mask = 0x80 ; i < 8 ; i ++, mask >>= 1)
               {
                   states_time[i]++;
                   // Compare the previous state and present state on each pin
                   uint8_t state = mask & sensors_states;
                   if((mask & prev_sensors_states) != state)
                   {
                       // Here you can use the state of the pin and the duration of that state.
                       // Remember that when 'state' is > 0 it means that previous state of the
                       // pin was '0' and if if 'state' is == 0 then the previous pin state
                       // was '1' (negation).
                       do_something_with_pin_change(states_time[i], state);

                       states_time[i] = 0;
                   }
               }
               // Save the previous states of the pins
               prev_sensors_states = sensors_states;
               // Clear the flag to await next data update
               read_flag = 0;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

If You will try to use FreeRTOS You could use `ulTaskNotifyTake` and `vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR`, instead of using `read_flag`, to implement a simple mechanism which will notify a task from the interrupt that the port has been read. The processor will go into idle state for a while and you could then invoke a sleep function to minimize power consumption.

I don't know what You want to do with this data so I've invoked `do_something_with_pin_change` function to indicate the point where You can use the data.

To sum up for this solution You would only use one interrupt and of course 8 pins.